# Redefinition of enumerator / Semantic issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got serious issues with XCode right now and i cant really figure out what to do, or even whats wrong.

The project i'm working on was working perfectly yesterday, but today when i started it i got like 20 "Redefinition of enumerator" errors, and to the point where "Too many errors emitted. Stopping now".

The wierd part is that ALL my backups of the project does this aswell. Even the ones from 2,3 or 4 days ago which hasnt been altered.

No other project seems to be affected by this.

I've tried Cleaning the build, removing Derived data, checking for duplicate files somehow (even though that shouldnt be possible), all linker seems to be in order. Anyone got any tips for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

you should import

`#import "Facebook.h"`
instead

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Comment: unbelieveble .. you saved my day.

Comment: Can you rephrase the answer slightly - is the `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDk.h>' the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact problem about "Redefinition of enumerator" errors coming out of nowhere.
The problem was that accidentally (maybe some unintended drag with the mouse) I had copied one of the project directories into some other, thus duplicating it.

On the other hand I use git and generally was using 'git status -uno' which hides untracked files.

So I was not seeing the untracked duplicated directory that was duplicating enums in the project, from my perspective I had a clean HEAD with weird errors :S

Lesson learned: use .gitignore rather than '-uno' option

Answer (score 1):

This issue still happens in 2019 smh.
If you get this go check **File->Workspace Settings** and set build system to **Legacy Build System**. This should fix the issue.

Comment: Mine was on Legacy Build so I changed it the New Build, failed to build with different error, put it back to Legacy and it worked like normal. Does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was really stuck. But found that the project folder nam had white spaces. I changed that and the error went off!

> Eg: Changed folder name **My Project** to **MyProject**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone has the same problem, who pulled out hair for hours/days.
Let's double check and remove redundant **Header Search Paths**, delete **Derived Data** if needed.
After that, the issue will be resolved.